# Not able to run TestNG Suite (Selenium Webdriver)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am new to TestNg , Selenium.

My problem is I am not able to run my TestNG suite. When I click my testNg suite (By right clicking crossBrowser.xml and click TestNG Suite), It is not running, It does not show any error in the console.

Please find the code I am using.

VerifyTitle.java

```
package testNGTestPack;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;




public class VerifyTitle {
    WebDriver driver;

    @Test
    @Parameters("browserName")
    public void verifyTitle(String browserName){

        if(browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("firebox")) {
            driver=new FirefoxDriver();     }
        else if(browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")){
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\driver\\chromedriver.exe");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
        }
        else if(browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("IE")){             
            System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "D:\\driver\\IEDriverServer.exe");             
             driver=new InternetExplorerDriver();   
            }
        driver.manage().window().maximize();             
        driver.get("http://www.facebook.com");       
        //driver.quit();
    }
}
```

crossBrowser.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
   <suite name="testNGTestPack">
     <test name="Test">
        <parameter name="browserName" value="firebox"/>
        <classes>   
            <class name="testNGTestPack.VerifyTitle"/>
        </classes>
     </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

[image: Please see my folder structure]

**Eclipse Version : : Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)**

When right clicking against crossBrowser.xml which is showing Run As TestNg Suite. But clicking on it, it does not trigger any action. Even in console, it show any error.

Do I need to include any jar file? Please give me a solution

Comment: Your code works. Be sure your Firefox version is supported by selenium.

Comment: Turica, I have no problem with when running as Testng Test. It works with my FireFox version. The only problem, I am not able to run as TestNg Suite. When I click TestNg suite, its do nothing.

Comment: Anybody please help me, what is the worng with my testNg Suite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you need to create a new configuration for this.

Select your testng.xml file > Run as > Run Configuration > Click on TestNG on left panel > Right click and and CLick on new >  Click on Suite > Browse xml and click on run.

Please try and let me know.

Thanks
Mukesh

Comment: hi mukesh i had just started integrating maven build tool to eclipse. i got stuck in creating testng.xml to my sample java class when i right click on the java class.